# How to add consumable in-app product in New Google Play Console version

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-console

After the update to new version in Google Play Console, there's no option to choose between consumable or non-consumable in-app product!!

> All new created in-app products are non-consumable by default!, and
> there's no option to change it.

**How can I create new consumable in-app product in Google Play Console new version?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That option did not exist on the old console either.

It is your code that decides if a product is consumable or not by calling `billingClient.consumeAsync()` or not

Comment: Please can provide the documentation for this method ?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#consumeasync

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

Comment: Thanks, it was new for me this idea,